# mysql query different meta_key and display them separately

Tags: mysql, wordpress, foreach

I am a new to mysql and my question is difficult for me to describe. Wordpress stores a lot of postmeta as various meta_keys that contain various meta_values. I'm having a problem trying to query by a particular meta_key but and then being able to display 2 different meta_keys and their values. Here is what I have so far which properly displays all of the video urls from a particular wordpress category...

```
<?php
$myquery=mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM foy_postmeta AS pm
INNER JOIN foy_term_relationships AS tr ON (pm.post_id = tr.object_id)
INNER JOIN foy_posts AS p ON (pm.post_id = p.ID)
WHERE pm.meta_key='video_url'
AND tr.term_taxonomy_id='27'
AND p.post_status='publish'
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
");

$rows = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($myquery)){
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```

?>

And then I put this into rows within my html which properly displays all of the video titles and their paths...

```
   <?php
   foreach( $rows as $row ) {
      <div>my video title: <?php echo $row["post_title"]; ?></div>
      <div>my video url: <?php echo $row["meta_value"]; ?></div>
   }
   ?>
```

Now, what I would like to do is to keep this same row list, but to also write out another meta_key and it's value, something like this....

```
   <?php
   foreach( $rows as $row ) {
      <div>my video title: <?php echo $row["post_title"]; ?></div>
      <div>my video url: <?php echo $row["meta_value"]; ?></div>
      <div>my video format is: <?php echo $row["meta_value"]; ?></div>
   }
   ?>
```

But I'm not sure how I can display 2 meta_values within the same loop since they have separate meta_keys within the same postmeta table.

Comment: are the meta values related to the same post?

Comment: Yes. All the meta_values are tied to the same post. Each post might have several meta keys within the "meta_key" column and then those have individual meta_values. So I'm looking to display two of those meta_keys and their values all from the same post id. Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use wp_query for this. Its the wordpress database query for posts which makes things easier when dealing with post_meta.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

for example for the above

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'meta_query' => array(
   array(
       'key' => 'video_url',

   )
),
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'your taxonomy name here',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'whatever'
    )
),
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
 );

$query= new wp_query($args);
?>

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
var_dump($meta);

?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

now for every post you can access the post_meta (check what the array var_dumps for the keys)

or if you want to persist with mysql use a foreach loop for each row and pass the id to get_post_meta($id); you can then use the postmeta for every row.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The get_post_meta makes sense. But very sorry, I hadn't mentioned that I'm using mysql_query because it is actually a page that is not a wordpress site, but it is pulling data from a database that is using wordpress....very confusing. Sorry about that!

Comment: I did get a workaround of my problem by removing the specific meta_key within the query so that the multiple meta_keys and their meta_values will all be part of the query. And then I was able to use if statements to populate the fields I needed. I'll post my answer for further comments as my version seems messy.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that although works, I'm thinking there is a better way to do it. I removed the specific meta_key item within the query so that I could grab all meta_keys, and then used if statements within the foreach loop to create variables of the particular ones I wanted to display:

```
<?php
$myquery=mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM foy_postmeta AS pm
INNER JOIN foy_term_relationships AS tr ON (pm.post_id = tr.object_id)
INNER JOIN foy_posts AS p ON (pm.post_id = p.ID)
WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id='27'
AND p.post_status='publish'
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
");

$rows = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($myquery)){
  $rows[] = $row;
} 

<?php
  foreach( $rows as $row ) {
    // sets video url and video layout values as variables
    if ($row["meta_key"] == "video_url" ){ $videourl = $row["meta_value"]; }
    if ($row["meta_key"] == "video_layout" ){ $videolayout = $row["meta_value"]; }
    if ($row["meta_key"] == "video_url" ){ 
?>
     <div>my video url: <?php echo $videourl ?></div>
     <div>my video format is: <?php echo $videolayout ?></div>
<?php 
    } 
  }
?>
```